# call a non-static method from static method in abstract class (c++)

Tags: c++, abstract

someone know by chance about a workaround to call non-static method from static method in abstract class in C++?

for example, i have the following abstract class:

```
class aClass
{
  public: 
   static int check();
   virtual int check_deep()=0;
}
```

and i want to call to check_deep() form check()

thanks in advance,
Judith.

Comment: the thing you want to do doesn't make any sense. if you need help it would be better to know *what* you want to do, not *how*. what do these function do?

Comment: You need an instance of `aClass` to call the virtual method `check_deep`: which one should it be?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your static method's signature to receive a reference (or pointer) to an instance of `aClass` to do so:

```
class aClass
{
  public: 
   static int check(aClass& instance);
   virtual int check_deep()=0;
}

int aClass::check(aClass& instance)
{
     return aClass.check_deep();
}
```

The design **[smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)** somehow though!

Answer (score 0):

No. And it would not make sense, since a non-static method is bound to an instance of the class (to which you refer as `this`) while a static method is not bound to any instance: there would be no `this` to bind `check_deep` to from `check`.

Obviously, supposing that you will be calling it from a subclass, otherwise `check_deep` is pure virtual and you won't be able to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it. Non-static method requires an object to act on, and in your case when it is pure virtual the object even decides which exact method will be called. You absolutely need an object of aClass type to call check_deep.